# Handling toast notification action trigger from background task - UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, background-task

I have a background task for a UWP which can be triggered once a push notification occurs, but I want to trigger the task for normal toast notifications activated when the App is in background.

I found that `ToastNotificationActionTrigger` can do so but it can only trigger the BG task when the activation type is set to background for that notification.

Is there a work around for differentiating when a toast notification is received and activated with App in BG with that of a toast notification activated in Foreground.

Comment: Why don't you just set the activation type of the toast to Background? That's how you make a toast activate a background task when clicked rather than launching your app.

Comment: Because the toast notification is not specific for Background only. The case is that the notification can be received anytime in the BG or Foreground. It just that a difference at what App state it was tapped is required

Comment: Your scenario still isn't making sense. Can you more clearly describe the exact scenario from the user's perspective?

Answer (score 0):

[ToastNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.aspx) class has an [Activated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.activated.aspx) event so you can attach an event handler once you create it to receive Activation events without a background task.

> Occurs when user activates a toast notification through a click or
>   touch. Apps that are running subscribe to this event.

In order to receive activation events from toasts that are created by previous instances of the app, you also need to enumerate current toast notifications on app launch using the [ToastNotificationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.aspx) class and attach an event handler to them as well.

Comment: Yes, but with your said method can you elucidate, how are we distinguishing between a toast notification activated on foreground and a toast notification received in background?

Comment: @user1917864 Obviuously the Activated event can get on foreground only. So if you get the activated event, you app is running, otherwise, you can only get it in background. So Activated event being raised or not distinguishes...I think your problem is XY problem anyway...

Comment: No, even when the App is in background, the activated event gets fired.

Comment: @user1917864 When the app is in background, your app executiion is suspened, how does the event gets fired?! If you mean after Resuming, then detach the handler on Suspended event.

Comment: You do NOT want to use the Activated event on the ToastNotification class. That event is only fired on the popup toast banner. It is NOT fired if the user clicks your toast via Action Center. This is not what you want.

Comment: I guess you mean it is NOT fired if user clicks toast via Action Center and the App is not running. Because if that is the case, the activated event still gets fired.